# eloquent does not saves an object to database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

The following code gives me an error "**Whoops, looks like something went wrong.**" in laravel 4

```
    $article = new Article;
    $article->name = "second article";
    $article->text = "second article desc";
    print($article->save());
```

**Here is my model**

```
<?php

class Article extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'article';

}
```

**question: how enable debugger see inside browser to see what going wrong ?**

Comment: Laravel 4 has a stack trace report that is enabled by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `app/config/app.php` set `debug` to `true`.

[`print`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) outputs the value of a string, you probably want to use [`var_dump()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/print_r) or Laravel's own [`dd()`](http://laravel.com/api/function-dd.html) that dumps the passed variable and ends the script.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issues where i created a table without migration. And used a Model. It was fetching the table but was not able to update. When ever i called $model->save() it throws me and error. Finally found that i forgot to add created_at and updated_at columns. I think laravel had made it mandatory for all tables.